# Dynamic Panel rule based on whether or not a contact exists in different data extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is it possible to configure dynamic panel rules based on whether or not a contact exists in a few different data extensions? 
Eg. show panel A if contact exists in DE A, show panel B if contact exists in DE B

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per your case, if the contact ID (unique identifier) is standard across all the DEs, you can achieve the solution using the [LookUp](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm) AMPscript function.

Here is an example:

```
%%[
SET @ContactIDValue = 'Your Contact ID'
SET @Lookup1 = Lookup('Data_Extension1','ContactIDField','ContactIDField',@ContactIDValue)
SET @Lookup2 = Lookup('Data_Extension2','ContactIDField','ContactIDField',@ContactIDValue)
SET @Lookup3 = Lookup('Data_Extension3','ContactIDField','ContactIDField',@ContactIDValue)

IF length(@Lookup1) > 0 AND NOT EMPTY(@Lookup1) THEN]%%
    <!--Your Dynamic Panel A-->
%%[ELSEIF length(@Lookup2) > 0 AND NOT EMPTY(@Lookup2) THEN]%%
    <!--Your Dynamic Panel B-->
%%[ELSEIF length(@Lookup3) > 0 AND NOT EMPTY(@Lookup3) THEN]%%
    <!--Your Dynamic Panel C-->
%%[ELSE]%%
    <!--Your Default Panel-->
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

**Breakdown:**

In the above AMPscript, set the value of the contactID to an AMPscript variable `@ContactIDValue` which is then used to compare on the multiple lookups depending on the number of the Data Extensions you want to lookup on. Then you compare the lookup values using `IF` and `ELSEIF` statements, moreover the `ELSE` will set to a default panel if the contact doesn't exist on all those Data Extensions.